# Deploying init vapor 4 project causing error

Tags: swift, vapor, server-side-swift

I've tried deploying an init vapor 4 project on Heroku and Digital Ocean and keep getting the same error:

```
error: https://github.com/vapor/vapor.git has no Package.swift manifest for version 4.4.1
```

my swift package is pointing to:

```
.package(url: "https://github.com/vapor/vapor.git", from: "4.5.0")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing your `.build` directory and Package.resolved and trying again